# I want my users to only access my php files, if they try to access the folders I want to include my page 404 file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, include

I have my **query string** to include my pages, in my homepage like you see below and it is working fine, Im including my pages fine.

But something wrong is happening and Im not finding how I can solve this.

**I will try to expain my isse with an example:** I have a folder "teachers" inside I have two pdf documents and a page "documents.php".
To acess this documents page, Im acessing: "htp://localhost/website/teachers/documents", and it is working fine.

But If I acess  "htp://localhost/website/teachers/", Im able to acess my pdf documents and my page as you see in my image below.

[image]

But I dont want this, I want that If some user tries to acess "htp://localhost/website/teachers/", I want to include my 404 file (`require_once('inc/404.php');`)

**My query string:**

```
@$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = explode('/', $url);
$url[0] = ($url[0] == NULL ? 'index' : $url[0]);

if(file_exists('inc/'.$url[0].'.php')){
     require_once('inc/'.$url[0].'.php');
}
elseif(file_exists($url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php')){
     require_once($url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[2].'.php');
}
elseif(@file_exists($url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
     require_once($url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
}
else{
     require_once('inc/404.php');
}
```

Do you see what Im doing wrong to not be having the result I want?

**My htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: How does `htp://localhost/website/teachers/documents` bring you anywhere? There is no folder inside the teachers folder as you've shown in your picture.

Comment: I dont know if I understand clearly your question, but, I have a folder teachers inside my website folder. Inside teachers I have my documents.php file, so when I acess "http://localhost/website/teachers/documents" Im acessing my documents page...

Comment: Im acessing like this, because of my htacesss file, so I dont use documents.php file, but documents its not a folder, it is a php file, my documents page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier solution.

Add this line to the beginning of your .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This way, you won't be able to see the folder contents.

---

EDIT: htaccess rule solution (which is in `website` folder)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /website/inc/404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/

RewriteRule ^teachers/$ - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Justin lurman, your solution works fine. But I want to include my own 404.php file, and with your code in my .htaccess file Im gettin an default "Error 403"...

Comment: In which folder is your htaccess ?

Comment: Inside "Website" folder.

Comment: Does your file `404.php` is in `/website/inc/` ? If so, see my edited answer ("edit" part) and try it

Comment: Yes it is Justin lurman. And it seems that is working fine, however, I have a menu with 3 levels, and I have a folder "schools" inside my "website" folder, where I have one folder "1st_grade", 
other "2nd_grade", and other "3rd_grade", to access one school page for example of "1st_grade school", 
I use http://192.168.1.67/website/schools/1st_grade/school_page, and it is working fine, but I have the same problem if I try to acess http://192.168.1.67/website/schools/1st_grade/, Im able to see the files inside this folder.

Comment: Do see how can I solve this? Because RewriteRule ^schools/$ - [R=404,L] its not enough because 1st_grade it is a folder inside my schools folder..

Comment: Hmm, never mind, I think that "RewriteRule ^schools/1st_grade/$ - [R=404,L]" solves this, right?

Comment: If you want to hide `1st_grade` folder then yes your last rule should be ok

Comment: And also, instead of "ErrorDocument 404 /website/inc/404.php" Im using "ErrorDocument 404 /website/404.php" because with "/inc/" Im having one issue including my 404.php file, that should be because of my query string, but without "/inc/", it seems that is working fine. Thanks :)